# Is creating a gRPC client stream async?

Tags: go, stream, grpc

I have the following .proto file

```
service ChatService {
    rpc Login(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {}
    rpc Logout(LogoutRequest) returns (LogoutResponse) {}
    rpc Stream(stream StreamRequest) returns (stream StreamResponse) {}
}
```

Initially any client will call the `Login` method and then followed by `Stream`.  If a client logs into the service (server) a broadcast message is sent on the streaming clients.  I want to test this functionality in a unit test and this is what I have so far:

```
func Test_Login_ShouldBroadcastLoginNotificationThroughStream(t *testing.T) {
    waitc := make(chan struct{})
    loginSuccess := false

    ctx := context.Background()
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "bufnet", grpc.WithContextDialer(dialer()), grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to dial bufnet: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    client1 := NewChatServiceClient(conn)
    // step 1: log in the client
    r, err := client1.Login(ctx, &LoginRequest{Name: "test"})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Error logging in client")
    }

    // step 2: start streaming
    md := metadata.New(map[string]string{tokenHeader: r.Token})
    ctx = metadata.NewOutgoingContext(ctx, md)
    sc1, err := client1.Stream(ctx) // THIS DOES NOT APPEAR TO BE BLOCKING
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Error streaming in client1")
    }
    t.Log("finished setting up client 1 stream")

    // // step 3: start listning for messages coming in
    go func() {
        res, _ := sc1.Recv()
        t.Logf("got a response from client1 %+v", res)
        m := res.Event.(*StreamResponse_ClientLogin)
        if m.ClientLogin.Name == "test2" {
            loginSuccess = true
        }
        close(waitc)
    }()

    // need to pause for a few seconds before starting client 2 in order for the streaming to start
    // step 4: create another client
    client2 := NewChatServiceClient(conn)
    _, err = client2.Login(ctx, &LoginRequest{Name: "test2"})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Error logging in client")
    }
    t.Log("client 2 logged in")

    <-waitc
    sc1.CloseSend()
    // no need to start streaming here since client 1 is streaming
    if !loginSuccess {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

The steps are as follows

1. Client 1 logs in.
2. Client 1 calls stream and waits for new login messages
3. Client 2 logs in, at this point the server will send a login success message to Client 1

My problem is that in `step 2`, although the client calls `Stream`, before the server can setup the streams (complete the method) for `client1` it has already started processing the `client2` login method.  I was under the impression that that  `sc1, err := client1.Stream(ctx)` is synchronous and would block until the server processes that method, but this does not appear to be the case and it seems to return immediately.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: What happens that makes you think the `sc1, err := client1.Stream(ctx)` call is async? What is the order of the logs that you get?

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but what you're describing is very much NOT a unit test. It clearly depends on multiple "units". I'd call it an integration test.

Comment: I changed the title because `Stream` is the name of *your particular* grpc method

Comment: To answer your question, if I understand it correctly, you might be able to achieve what you want with the call option `grpc.WaitForReady(true)`

Comment: thanks everyone, I eneded up putting a `time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)` into the unit test and it worked.  I think its probably something wrong with the in memory streaming and don't want to spend more time on it, it works perfectly fine under normal conditions.